# PHP get p element from div

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a something like this in html

```
<div id="files" class="files"></div>
```

And Javascript dynamically adds

```
<p>File Name</p>
```

when file is uploaded. 
PHP

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['add_task'])){
   $req_fields = array('area-id','jig-id','description','frequency-id');
   validate_fields($req_fields);
   if(empty($errors)){
     $t_area_id  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['area-id']));
     $t_jig_id  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['jig-id']));
     $t_description  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['description']));
     $t_frequency   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['frequency-id']));
     $date    = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['date-done']));
     if ($_GET['file'])
        $file_name = $_GET['file'];
    else
        $file_name = "No File";
     $query  = "INSERT INTO tpm_tasks_list ("; 
     $query .=" area_id,jig_id,description,frequency,filename,last_date";
     $query .=") VALUES (";
     $query .=" '{$t_area_id}','{$t_jig_id}','{$t_description}' ,'{$t_frequency}','{$file_name}', '{$date}'";
     $query .=")";
     if($db->query($query)){
       $session->msg('s',"Task added ");
       redirect('add_task.php', false);
     } else {
       $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to add!');
       redirect('add_task.php', false);
     }

   } else{
     $session->msg("d", $errors);
     redirect('add_task.php',false);
   }

 }

?>
```

JS I am using ready script for file upload i found somwhere, as I am not good with JS/Java.

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io' ?
                '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : 'upload/server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

On the same page I have a form, that sends information to mysql. 
I need to get that file name if exist and somehow pass it together with other information in php.

The only thing I found, is using DomDocument, however I don't think I know how to save current html structure (with file uploaded) and pass it to xml ?

I also found I can pass filename to url but that refreshes the page which I don't want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you forgot to add code..

Comment: If you want to do it without refreshing the page, the for form submit use ajax

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) Where is the code you have written so far?

Comment: does your code upload file? seems like you are using jquery fileupload plugin

Answer (score 2):

Without refreshing the page if you want to submit your form along with other necessary information you need to use ajax technique. Include jQuery in your project and you can do ajax request like this:

```
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    var file_data = $('#yourimage').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data); // add other form elements

    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script 
        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(php_script_response) {
            alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

`Upload.php` is the server side script which will handle the form request and return a response depending on your situation. So you can get file name and other data you have appended to form data.

Comment: looks good, however that will require to change everything in my code, but I guess it will be a good change, as I can't see any other option.

Comment: Yes that's the way to do non-refreshing page request. The ajax technique